# Construct and apply a rotation matrix by doing the following:

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a hard time with starting this question:

Create a $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix $A$ that is different from $I$.

Comment: What does the question mean to you?  What is a $2\times 2$ rotation matrix?

Comment: Think about taking a vector $(x,y)$ and how you would describe rotating it through an angle $\theta $

Answer (score 0):

The main point of this question is the following, $2 \times 2$-matrices acts on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, simply by multiplication by a vector. What you want to do is to find a matrix that will presserve the length of the vector, but rotates it.

Comment: 1/2  -√3/2                                                                                                 √3/2  1/2                 this is my matrix that rotates through pi/3  is this right or not

Comment: @MichaelPryor Yes and can you see a pattern there? If not, you should look at the cosinus and sinus functions